# Why FetchType.EAGER doesn't work in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, eager-loading

My application with JPA (Hibernate) and Spring. My enitites are:

**Department**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16 )
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16 )
    private UUID uuid;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "login", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_fk", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

}
```

**DAO** for Department:

```
@Repository("departmentDao")
public class DepartmentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public UUID save(Department entity) {
        log.info("Department entity will be persisted", entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity.getUuid();
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Department> getAllWithUsers() {
        log.info("Select all departments");
        CriteriaQuery<Department> criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Department.class);
        Root<Department> root = criteria.from(Department.class);
        criteria.select(root);
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Whan I run the code in Main class it joins the entities:

**Main**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring.xml");
UserDao userDao = (UserDao) context.getBean("userDao");
DepartmentDao departmentDao = (DepartmentDao) context.getBean("departmentDao");

Department newDep = new Department("WebDepartment", new Date());
departmentDao.save(newDep);

User newUser1 = new User("Test1", newDep);
User newUser2 = new User("Test2", newDep);
userDao.save(newUser1);
userDao.save(newUser2);

List<Department> deps = departmentDao.getAllWithUsers();

//deps
//[Department{name='WebDepartment', users = ['Test1', 'Test2']}]
```

Whan I run  a unit test with the same code, the department has empty list of users:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/spring-test.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void daoTests() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Department newDep = new Department("WebDepartment", new Date());
        departmentDao.save(newDep);

        User newUser1 = new User("Test1", newDep);
        User newUser2 = new User("Test2", newDep);
        userDao.save(newUser1);
        userDao.save(newUser2);
        List<Department> deps = departmentDao.getAllWithUsers();

        //deps
        //[Department{name='WebDepartment', users = []}]
    }
}
```

So, my question is: why **EAGER** works in Main, but in test it doesn't?

Comment: The difference is your unit test run within a transaction

Comment: I create User-entities inside one transaction and tries to get them inside another transaction? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Can you please show the constructor of the User entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are not adding the new User to the list of users in the Department.

Your constructor must look like:

```
public User(
            // other fields, 
            Department department) {
   // set all fields.

   department.getUsers().add(this);
}
```

In the Main it's working because you have two transactions and in the reading is in a separate transaction and the Department is fetched from DB.

But in the Unit Test it returns the Department from the memory where the users list is empty.

**It's very important to keep your relationships set correctly before saving entities.**

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Thanks! But one more question. Does saving to db or reading from db in unit tests create real transactions? Or all the manipulations with data are inside java memory?

Comment: If you use Transactional in Unit test with SpringRunner then it creates a database transaction and by default does a rollback at the end of the test method